# Build a procecure that returns a JSON Object (ORACLE 19)

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I need to build a procedure that has a couple of varchars that I need to merge into a JSON object which should be the output of the procedure.

For example:

```
PROCEDURE json (p_input varchar2, o_json (datatype?) is

v_input_      varchar2(200);
v_str1        varchar2(2000);
v_str2        varchar2(2000);

begin

v_str1 := 'test1';
v_str2 := 'test2';

end;
```

What I want to do is to create the output as a JSON consisting of the two varchars v_str1 and v_str2 with the KEY values as "Machine" and "Serial".

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks for the kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE json(
  i_str1  IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_str2  IN  VARCHAR2,
  o_json  OUT CLOB
)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'Machine' VALUE i_str1,
           KEY 'Serial'  VALUE i_str2
         )
  INTO   o_json
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_json CLOB;
BEGIN
  json('a', 'b', v_json);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_json);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> {"Machine":"a","Serial":"b"}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41a2e05450638539566a9dd098ce0d8a)*

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `JSON_OBJECT`:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (KEY 'Machine' IS some_object.Machine,
                    KEY 'Serial'  IS some_object.Serial ) "your JSON"
  FROM (SELECT 'test1' AS Machine
             , 'test2' AS Serial
          FROM dual) some_object;
```

[reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370)